# Android XML equivalent of C++'s "using namespace..."?

Tags: java, android, c++, xml

easy yes or no question here. I'm new to Java/XML programming in general, but this in particular pertains to Android.
In C++ there's the "using namespace std;" that can be put at the top so you don't have to type "std::" before every identifier.
Similarly I'm learning quickly in Android I have to type "android:" before any identifier, so I'm wondering if there's a way to expedite the process and do something like C++ can do, and just put it once at the top instead of typing it on almost every line?
Thank you.

Comment: Well you *shouldn't* do that in C++. :D

Comment: The reason of the std namespace is not to bother you with `std::`, that´s just one side of it. As Joseph Mansfield said, don´t do it.

Comment: @deviantfan I understand it's bad practice in c++ & that's not really what it's for, but in xml would it be more acceptable if there's even a way to do something like it or with that functionality? That's mainly my question.

Answer (score 1):

No.

In Android XML, the elements are not in any namespace.

In XML in general, element attributes cannot have a default namespace. Either they are in an explicit namespace such as `android:` or they are in no namespace at all.

The default `xmlns="something"` default namespace prefix only applies to elements.

You *could* rename the namespace alias to a shorter one, though. For example, change

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to e.g.

```
xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

so you only have to type `a:` instead of `android:`.

I wouldn't *suggest* doing so though. Having the namespace prefix as `android` is a convention that makes it easier to co-operate with other Android developers and tools, and mix code from various sources.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking I could just find & change the "a"'s back to "android" later when I'm done, would be a lot easier than typing it repeatedly. Anyway thank you very much! Would up you but I'm not at 15 reputation yet

Comment: I would avoid changing the XML namespaces just because you are lazy. Yes, being familiar with C++, Java is going to be much more verbose than what you are used to, but you really should stick with the conventions of each language and not try to think of Java as C++. They are different languages, with different practices and different ways to manage your code. 

In addition, I know Android Studio will help complete your code for you(and Eclipse does too, although AS's is much better). When I type "a" in an XML file, I can simply hit enter to have the full "android:" bit added for me.